# wrap images in a div so doesn't exceed max width

Tags: image, html, word-wrap

I'm showing some images and I would like them to go to the next line when they arrive to the div max width limit.

I've tried many things, none of them worked.

This is the problem, the images getting out of the DIV:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GsVW.png

I would like to have the last icon underneath the first one, and so. I mean, I don't want them to exceed the div width. When they arrive to the limit, to automatically respect the limit and go to the next line.

It shouldn't be difficult, i just don't know how.

This is the html:

```
<div class="awards-member">
<a href="blabla"><img src="blabla.png"></a>
<a href="blabla1"><img src="blabla1.png"></a>
<a href="blabla2"><img src="blabla2.png"></a>
<a href="blabla3"><img src="blabla3.png"></a>
<a href="blabla4"><img src="blabla4.png"></a>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
.awards-member {
    width: 150px;
    }

.awards-member img{
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Any idea? thanks a lot men!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.awards-member {
    width: 150px;
    white-space:normal;
    }
```